# Enable CORS only for specific domain from HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, cors, httpmodule

I have asp.net web forms application which I want to enable CORS only to the specific domains. I am trying to achieve this using HttpModule.

e.g. My site is https://mysiteex.com

CORS should be enabled from https://third-party1.com and https://third-party2.com

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for. Place `using System.Web;` and the code below into your Global.asax file for the Application_BeginRequest event.

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable CORS for cross-site scripting.

        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var response = context.Response;

        // enable CORS. "*" = all domains, substitute your own as needed.
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            response.End();
        }
    }
```